# A problem occurs when trying to change a button's frame in an animation block.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, uikit, uibutton

I created a button, with a custom image and displayed it in a frame.
Now I'm trying to change the button's frame, inside an animation block.
Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work - the frame doesn't change as expected.

I have written the following code:

```
UIButton *movingButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"A_normal_image.png"];
[movingButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
movingButton.frame = CGRectMake(160, 240, 0, 0);
[movingButton addTarget:self action:@selector(moveButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:movingButton];

CGRect newFrame CGRectMake(20, 120, 44, 88);
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{ movingButton.frame = newFrame; }];
[movingButton release];
```

Am I missing something? How should I do that then?

Thanks in advance,
Sagiftw

Comment: What is happening in the animation?

Comment: I changed the frame of the button, so its origin and size should have been changed. What's happening is that only the origin is changing, but the size of the image is the size of the frame newFrame. I mean: CGRectMake(160, 240, 44, 88) turns to:  CGRectMake(20, 120, 44, 88).

Comment: Shouldn't the frame be changing from **CGRectMake(160, 240, 0, 0)** to CGRectMake(20, 120, 44, 88), instead of what you posted above? If what you posted above is actually correct, then the size of the frame is being set before the animation, right? And then the animation changes the origin from (160, 240) to (20, 120). Let me know which of the two is the case.

Answer (score 0):

You should use floats instead of ints:

```
movingButton.frame = CGRectMake(160, 240, 0, 0);
```

to:

```
movingButton.frame = CGRectMake(160.0f, 240.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

Comment: I know but this method also accepts ints. Using floats won't change anything and this code still won't work and the frames won't be changed.